# iOS Bluetooth and Wi-Fi data transfer

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi

I need to send data to the printer via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi (PCL commands).

Bluetooth: As I understand it requires special MFi printers. Is there a way to transfer data to other Bluetooth adapters?

Wi-Fi: I found a mention of a certain closed API. Is this the only way?

For example for Android I can write:

```
BluetoothDevice device = ...;
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord
(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(...);

SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(_address, _port);
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(socketAddress);
OutputStream os1 = socket.getOutputStream();
os1.write(...);
```

How can I do something like this for iOS?